# Finding the uses of a specific cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working with a purpose-built excel software with 64 worksheets, a lot of named ranges and formulas. I want to target a specific cell and figure out how that cell is used in named ranges and formulas. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Comment: Find in Formulas and Trace cell dependents comes to mind... More? Maybe not.

Comment: @Hannu I tried Trace cell dependents and it is all I need. Thank you

Comment: @Hannu: You might then undelete your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Formulas > Trace dependents / precedents
2. To see where the cell is used in a named range, hit F3 and click Paste List, which generates the contents of all named ranges as text.
3. Select the formula of the first named range, and press F2 then Enter, repeatedly for all names. Now redo #1.

Bonus tip: CTRL+[ and CTRL+] acts similar to dependents / precedents, but uses selections rather than arrows. You can press say CTRL+[ multiple times to delve deeper into yet another level of reference. Also very convenient to highlight dependencies in different colours.